# Load switch unused pin: floating or ground through a resistor

Tags: power, emc

I am using [TPS1HA08BQPWPRQ1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps1ha08-q1.pdf) in my design. This is for automotive application.

Regarding unused pins TI gave the following recommendations.

May I know which one will be better: floating or connecting to ground using a resistor.

The resistor value suggested by the manufacturer is 15 kΩ.

Will floating pin cause any EMI or EMC issues?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the datasheet, R<sub>PROT</sub> is a protection resistor to be used in case of a reversed battery connection.

If you are sure that the battery will never be connected in reverse polarity then you may left the unused pins floating. But if there's a risk then you should implement a reverse polarity protection with either a diode or a MOSFET, or place the R<sub>PROT</sub> resistors as suggested.

For other details read section 9.3.1.5.

Comment: Thank you.Will floating pins cause any EMI EMC issues

Comment: @Hari I don't see any potential EMI-related issues, and datasheet doesn't mention such thing. If there was any chance of issue then it'd be indicated in the under "IMPACTS" column.

Answer (score 1):

They mention two purposes for it:

- Reverse polarity protection, in which case this resistor is just an oddball solution and you ought to handle that elsewhere for the whole PCB supply and not just one IC. Their concerns for reverse polarity protection is when no other protection is present than those built-in in the high-side driver.

  Common solutions to reverse polarity involve either just a simple schottky in series, or a reversed PMOS in series with gate pulled towards ground. Search for "MOSFET polarity protection", there will be solutions posted here on this site.

  Assuming you already have reverse polarity protection or that it doesn't apply to your product, then it is nonsense to ground not used pins with 15k. Just tie them directly to ground. Indeed it is also good practice in general to tie input pins to ground rather than leave them floating, to reduce vulnerability to EMI or ESD. The datasheet does claim that SEL2 pin must have a path to ground in case of reverse polarity.
- Protecting MCU I/O pins against unexpected events such as transients, shorts, ESD. This has nothing to do with this IC as such either, but is common best design practices. Typically we would use a standard value 10k series resistor towards MCU GPIO pins. We would not pick a semi-exotic value like 15k just for the sake of increasing BoM costs.

I don't quite see why the datasheet preaches miscellaneous common best practices instead of focusing on the specific IC, but I suppose it doesn't hurt...